# Is there a way to jump from method to method in Textmate?

Tags: ide, textmate

It always seems to me that traversing through a text file is best done by a mouse in Textmate, because ALT+UP and ALT+DOWN seem to work so unpredictably.  Is there a shortcut that I'm missing that would let me just jump up or down from one method to the next?  I've been looking but can't seem to find this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a built-in process for this, but adding it using a macro took only about a minute. I opened up a PHP file. Since every method in PHP has the word `function` in it, I began recording a macro, performed a find for `function`, stopped recording, saved the macro, assigned the key equivalent Cmd-Opt-F. Now wherever my cursor is in the file, I can press Cmd-Opt-F and it will take me to the next function. Using regular expressions in the search would allow you to further refine it so that you don't find the word `function` unless it's actually defining a method.